# Laravel Eloquent many-to-many relationship: Use explicit pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

How can I select an explicit table (with migration and model) as pivot table?

My models are

```
User
-id

Role
-id

user_role
-user_id
-role_id
-other_foreign_key_id
-other_attributes
-...
```

I know how many-to-many relations work in laravel in general. But in the documentation they only use the automatic generated joining table where I can't define an additional foreign key constraint or datatypes for additional columns.

What I want is that I have my own migration and model for the user_role table and use that as pivot but I don't know how to explicit link a defined table as pivot to a m-to-n relation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the `belongsToMany` method. The third argument is the `foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship`, while the fourth argument is the `foreign key name of the model that you are joining to`, like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id')
           ->withPivot(['other_foreign_key_id', 'other_attributes']);
```

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship with `withPivot()` method as done above:

You can use your `pivot attributes` using `pivot` like this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
    echo $role->pivot->other_attribute;
}
```

**UPDATE - Custom pivot model in Eloquent**

You can also define your own custom pivot model  like this:

```
class RoleUserPivot extends Pivot {
    // let's use date mutator for a field
    protected $dates = ['completed_at'];
}
```

Now, in order to let Eloquent grab this pivot model, we also need to override `newPivot` method on both `User` and `Role`:

```
// User model
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    if ($parent instanceof Role) {
        return new RoleUserPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}


// Role model
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    if ($parent instanceof User) {
        return new RoleUserPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

> See more about [Custom Pivot Tables](https://softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want the generated linking table because I for example can't specify the data types in the joining table or set a foreign key constraint.

Comment: You can also create a model for `role_user` table too, you can fullfill your requirements via crating the model for the joining table!

Comment: and how do I attach it in the models?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you!

Comment: I crafted the joining table with a migration and its own model. But what do I type as parameter in the belongsToMany() function to use my own defined table?

Comment: No, I don't want to use the auto-generated pivot table but my own crafted one!

Comment: I get you, see my updated answer for - Custom pivot model in Eloquent